# How to remove all no-change commits from git repository?

Tags: git, git-commit

Due to some conversion mechanism from Mercurial, my git repository has a lot of commits without any change? Is there a way to remove all these no-change commit from this repository?

It is ok to create another repository (with removed commits), keeping the main one intact.

Comment: If you know which ones they are, and if there are not too many, you could just squash them.

Comment: Do you want to keep the merge commits, most of which are also empty?

Comment: @ElpieKay no. I want to remove all empty commits.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the branch is `foo`. Try

```
git checkout foo
git rebase --root --no-keep-empty
```

It rebases all commits onto the root commit. If the branch has multiple root commits, it's the one along the first parent upon seeing a merge commit. `--no-keep-empty` prunes empty commits, including merge commits and normal commits. For those non-empty merge commits, it raises conflicts. Resolve the conflicts and continue `git rebase`.

Comment: "don't keep empty commits" is the default, so you don't have to add that here—not that it hurts...

Comment: @torek without `--no-keep-empty`, it does not prune a merge commit created by `git commit --allow-empty -m foo`. I'm using git bash for windows v2.29.2.

Comment: Did you change your default to include `--rebase-merges`? By default it (er, by "it" I mean "rebase") ditches all merges entirely. A recent Git did switch the default rebase from the old "am" (git am) backend to the "-m" backend though.

Comment: @torek empty merge commits are pruned by default without `--no-kee-empty`, but empty non-merge commits are not. How can I change the default to include `--rebase-merges`?

Comment: I'm not *sure* you can but there are some new config options. (I still have an older Git on most of my systems; I only build the current one in a Linux VM on the Mac sometimes.)

Comment: @torek according to the doc https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.29.0#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---no-keep-empty, it defaults to keep empty commits.

Comment: Ah, good, that means someone switched it around recently. It used to be no-keep-empty which created a problem. (At least I think it used to be the default even for `-m`. The old git-am based back end had to, and still does, drop empty commits because `git format-patch` drops them.)

Answer (score 0):

You want `git filter-branch` with grafts set to the ancestry you want. Write the correct ancestors for each commit into a grafts file (in `.git/info/grafts`) and say `git filter-branch --all` to rewrite all of history with the new ancestry structure.

Comment: Why not just use `--prune-empty`? Probably a good idea to add `--tag-name-filter cat` too.

Comment: @torek because OP wants to remove empty merges, whatever that means. prune-empty won't do it, I'd imagine because what's wanted is going to be specific to a situation. Other possibly-wanted options I'm leaving out, I've taken to intentionally leaving such things for the reader because I'm tired of doing work questioners should be doing anyway.